# AngularFire doesn't show data from Firebase Database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LdDwbIEpT4s) video. But I have trouble implementing it. This is the HTML file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Welcome to Firebase Hosting</title>        
        <!-- AngularJS -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>

        <!-- AngularFire -->
        <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/2.0.2/angularfire.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Firebase -->
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.3.0/firebase.js"></script>        

        <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app">
    <div id="message" ng-controller="MyController as ctrl">
      <pre>
{{ ctrl.object | json }}
          </pre>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And my app.js file is this.

```
(function(){

        // Initialize Firebase
        var config = {
                apiKey: "SOME KEY",
                authDomain: "tier2list.firebaseapp.com",
                databaseURL: "https://tier2list.firebaseio.com",
                storageBucket: "",
        };
        firebase.initializeApp(config);

        angular.module('app', ['firebase']).controller('MyController', function($firebaseObject){
                const rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child('tier2list');
                const ref = rootRef.child('object');
                this.object = $firebaseObject(ref);
        });

}());
```

This is my database structure.
[image]

But the result is as follows.

[image]

And there is no errors in the console as well. Database rules are as follows.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what your database looks like? It would seem that you might not have an 'object' child in your database, so it would make sense for null to be returned. One last thing that shouldn't be affecting anything but isn't good is that your storage bucket is empty in your config. That's a known firebase bug. It should show up if you go back and grab the config again.

Comment: I added database structure.

Comment: The script order does not look right. Firebase should be before AngularFire: https://github.com/firebase/angularfire#downloading-angularfire

Comment: I changed it but still I get same json. {
  "$id": "object",
  "$priority": null,
  "$value": null
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the path you synchronize:

```
const rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child('tier2list');
```

There is no child `tier2list` in your database, so you will get an empty object.

Instead, you're trying to synchronize the entire database, which you can do by:

```
const rootRef = firebase.database().ref()
```

Answer (score 1):

I was in the middle of this when Frank answered. He has the right answer, but here is what your database should look like in order to work with David's code:
[image]

In his walk through, he is already inside of the `angular` node, so that could be a little confusing.

I also created a Github repo for the project in case anyone is having trouble making it for themselves:
https://github.com/LukeSchlangen/angularFireQuickDemo